# Does WCF supports Peer-to-peer implementation?

Tags: wcf, p2p, net.p2p

I'm trying to implement peer-to-peer messaging and file sharing utility within LAN, So does WCF supports p2p? Does any one tried file sharing trough WCF?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it does. Please see [How To Design State Sharing In A Peer Network](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc700336.aspx):

> When researching the various ways in
>   which an election scenario might be
>   implemented, I discovered that there
>   is an attribute in WCF that allows you
>   to indicate the maximum number of hops
>   that a particular message will travel.
>   After seeing this, it became obvious
>   that there was a means for sharing
>   state in a peer network that not only
>   required no central server, but was
>   resilient to node drop-off and did not
>   require election. I call it Nearest
>   Peer Synchronization.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Check out the [NetPeerTCPBinding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.netpeertcpbinding.aspx).